# How to force lowercase URL in cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

How to force request lowercase in the URL in Cloudflare?

for example, if Cloudflare get requests for `https://example.com/signup/Test-Page-BLOG/` then it should be redirected to `https://example.com/signup/test-page-blog/`

Is that possible to use the Cloudflare page rule or any other method within Cloudflare?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not possible in cloudflare. Also, [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/force-lowercase-in-url/14168) community thread suggests that it cannot be done in cloudflare.

You can handle this at your webserver configuration itself.